# Increment by 3 for every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript

I just want to ask how to change the counter to increase by 3 every 2 seconds? I'm new to this so thank you in advance for the help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 3;
var b = 3;
function increment() {
    i++;
    b++;
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = i + b;
} 
setInterval('increment()', 2000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have one counter variable whose value will be increased by x like

```js
var i = 0;
var b = 3;

function increment() {
  i += b;
  document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = i;
}
setInterval(increment, 2000);
```

```html
<span id="number">0</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 0;
function increment() {
  i=i+3; //i+3
  document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = i;
}
```